# Shifting the domain

Tags: functions

Wee have a function $f$ with a domain $[0,2]$ and range $[0,1]$. What is the domain and range of $f(4-x)$?

The range is obviously the same, but I don't get why the domain is $[2,4]$. $f(4-x) = f(-x+4)$. For $f(-x)$ we have a domain of $[-2,0]$, and the $+4$ shifts the function 4 units to the left, so we get a domain of $[-6,-2]$. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f(-x+4) = f\big(-(x-4)\big)$. Since
$$
f(x) \quad \rightarrow \quad f(-x) \quad \rightarrow \quad f\big(-(x-4)\big),
$$
we can obtain $f(-x+4)$ from $f(x)$ by appropriate transformations. The domains are then:
$$
[0,2]  \quad \rightarrow \quad [-2,0]  \quad \rightarrow \quad [2,4]
$$